# context root issue using WAS 8.5 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, websphere, contextroot

I'm using Maven to build an ear that is to be published to a WAS8.5 server in eclipse.  Maven is generating the application.xml in /META-INF/application.xml.  But when I then deploy my ear to my WAS8.5 server, the context root of the war is being replaced with the URI.  For example, instead of the context root of app1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war being app1, it is the full URI (app1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war). Anybody have any suggestions??  The application.xml is found below.

Also, I am running Eclipse 4.5.1 with WebSphere 8.5.5. Thanks in advance!

```
 <!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd">
<application>
  <display-name>my_ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>app1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>app1</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>app2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

Comment: Are you deploying from Eclipse or via the admin console?

Comment: via eclipse. When I deploy via the admin console, the context roots are what they should be.